# How can I continue to next iteration in data step in SAS

Tags: loops, sas

I have a data step say :

```
data Tbl2;
    set Tbl;
    if something then do ;
       somethingelse;
       #HERE I WANT TO SKIP REST OF CODE AND GET NEXT ITERATION#
    end;
    some stuff that get usually executed unless something occur;
run;
```

When I use `continue` SAS tells me that it can only be used in a `do/end` block with iterations.
How can I achieve this trivial thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RETURN` statement does the magic.

Example from SAS help:

```
data survey;
   input x y;
   if x=y then return;
   put x= y=;
   datalines;
21 25
20 20
7 17
;
run;


x=21 y=25
x=7 y=17
```

In DO loops, `LEAVE` and `CONTINUE` statements can be used.